force the file to rerender in reactNative
The function updateVerification(placeholder, true) refuses to run.
It's supposed to run automatically when I open the screen, but what I noticed is that the function runs only when I resave the file. Literally,i have to open this file and then resave it, the function runs.
So, what I realized is that this file has to rerender automatically when the screen is opened.
PS: I tried to change the condition for running the function. I set country.name > 0. I also tried to set the inputValue and country in the dependencies of the useEffect but nothing works.
So I have set the file to rerender automatically or am I calling that function in the wrong way? Or what exactly?
export default function CountrySelect({ inputValue, placeholder, onChange,updateVerification }) {
    const [country, setCountry] = useState(inputValue || { cca2: 'AE', name: 'United Arab Emirates' });
    const handleSelect = (selectedCountry) => {
        setCountry(selectedCountry);
        onChange(selectedCountry.name);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        updateVerification(placeholder, true);
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{placeholder}</Text>
            <CountryPicker
                placeholder={placeholder}
                countryCode={country.cca2}
                onSelect={handleSelect} />
        </>
    );
};


that function will run when this components mount. its running again when you save the file due to fast refresh.  are you saying its not running on mount?

You have to add dependencies to useEffect:
    useEffect(() => {
        updateVerification(placeholder, true);
    }, [country]) // Add dependencies here to execute useEffect again


Nope I try it before
